# Android finger & tutorial

Tags: android

I don't know how this is called but I guess you know what I mean by looking at the screenshot (there sometimes also is a finger pointing at the bright part of the screen). 
Since this looks exactly like the little tutorial-like hint you get when you first install a new Android rom / start up a brand new Android phone: is there a standardized way or library or whatever for this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is **library**. Check it out: [Showcase View library](https://github.com/Espiandev/ShowcaseView)